# Using Ansible to automatically configure AWS autoscaling group instances

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, ansible, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation

I'm using Amazon Web Services to create an autoscaling group of application instances behind an Elastic Load Balancer. I'm using a CloudFormation template to create the autoscaling group + load balancer and have been using Ansible to configure other instances.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to design things such that when new autoscaling instances come up, they can automatically be provisioned by Ansible (that is, without me needing to find out the new instance's hostname and run Ansible for it). I've looked into Ansible's `ansible-pull` feature but I'm not quite sure I understand how to use it. It requires a central git repository which it pulls from, but how do you deal with sensitive information which you wouldn't want to commit?

Also, the current way I'm using Ansible with AWS is to create the stack using a CloudFormation template, then I get the hostnames as output from the stack, and then generate a hosts file for Ansible to use. This doesn't feel quite right – is there "best practice" for this?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, another way is just to simply run your playbooks locally once the instance starts. For example you can create an EC2 AMI for your deployment that in the `rc.local` file (Linux) calls `ansible-playbook -i <inventory-only-with-localhost-file> <your-playbook>.yml`. `rc.local` is almost the last script run at startup.

You could just store that sensitive information in your EC2 AMI, but this is a very wide topic and really depends on what kind of sensitive information it is. (You can also use private git repositories to store sensitive data).

If for example your playbooks get updated regularly you can create a cron entry in your AMI that runs every so often and that actually runs your playbook to make sure your instance configuration is always up to date. Thus avoiding having "push" from a remote workstation.

This is just one approach there could be many others and it depends on what kind of service you are running, what kind data you are using, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should use Ansible to configure new auto-scaled instances. Instead use Ansible to configure a new image, of which you will create an AMI (Amazon Machine Image), and order AWS autoscaling to launch from that instead.

On top of this, you should also use Ansible to easily update your existing running instances whenever you change your playbook.

Comment: Agree, I'd update AMI once rather than update every new instance under ASG. So, the process is: 1) pause autoscaling 2) update "old" instances 3) update ASG's AMI

Answer (score 0):

## Alternatives

There are a few ways to do this. First, I wanted to cover some alternative ways.

One option is to use Ansible Tower. This creates a dependency though: your Ansible Tower server needs to be up and running at the time autoscaling or similar happens.

The other option is to use something like packer.io and build fully-functioning server AMIs. You can install all your code into these using Ansible. This doesn't have any non-AWS dependencies, and has the advantage that it means servers start up fast. Generally speaking building AMIs is the recommended approach for autoscaling.

## Ansible Config in S3 Buckets

The alternative route is a bit more complex, but has worked well for us when running a large site (millions of users). It's "serverless" and only depends on AWS services. It also supports multiple Availability Zones well, and doesn't depend on running any central server.

I've put together a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/oskarpearson/aws-ansible-autoscaling-and-code-deploy/) that contains a fully-working example with Cloudformation. I also put together [a presentation for the London Ansible meetup](https://github.com/oskarpearson/aws-ansible-autoscaling-and-code-deploy/raw/master/docs/autoscaling-presentation.pptx).

Overall, it works as follows:

1. Create S3 buckets for storing the pieces that you're going to need to bootstrap your servers.
2. Save your Ansible playbook and roles etc in one of those S3 buckets.
3. Have your Autoscaling process run a small shell script. This script fetches things from your S3 buckets and uses it to "bootstrap" Ansible.
4. Ansible then does everything else.
5. All secret values such as Database passwords are stored in CloudFormation Parameter values. The 'bootstrap' shell script copies these into an Ansible fact file.

So that you're not dependent on external services being up you also need to save any build dependencies (eg: any .deb files, package install files or similar) in an S3 bucket. You want this because you don't want to require ansible.com or similar to be up and running for your Autoscale bootstrap script to be able to run. Generally speaking I've tried to only depend on Amazon services like S3.

In our case, we then also use AWS CodeDeploy to actually install the Rails application itself.

The key bits of the config relating to the above are:

1. [S3 Bucket Creation](https://github.com/oskarpearson/aws-ansible-autoscaling-and-code-deploy/blob/master/s3-buckets.json)
2. [Script that copies things to S3](https://github.com/oskarpearson/aws-ansible-autoscaling-and-code-deploy/blob/master/scripts/push-config-to-s3)
3. [Script to copy Bootstrap Ansible](https://github.com/oskarpearson/aws-ansible-autoscaling-and-code-deploy/blob/master/stack.json#L984-L1231). This is the core of the process. This also writes the Ansible fact files based on the CloudFormation parameters.
4. [Use the Facts](https://github.com/unboxed/aws-ansible-autoscaling-and-code-deploy/blob/632a218e3ffbd5037bbbef7778120713ed8ca420/ansible/roles/base-app/templates/etc/default/app-env-vars.j2#L15-L18) in the template.